# I thought that strings are immutable?

Tags: python, string

I've always thought that strings and tuples are immutable in Python. But now I've been confused with this function that I wrote (down below). When it's executed, I get a mutable string indeed. Am I missing something here?

```
def example():
    string = "/*Jon is @developer & musician"
    for char in string:
        if not char.isalpha():
            string = string.replace(char, '#')
    return(string)
```

Output:

```
>>> example()
'##Jon#is##developer###musician'
>>>
```

Thanks in advance for your explanation!

Comment: `.replace` will give you a new string

Comment: You never mutate a string anywhere in your code. *Where* do you think you mutated a string?

Comment: You create a NEW string, but you assign it in the SAME variable

Comment: Yup, you're missing something. You've just misunderstood what it means to mutate something. You aren't mutating the original string because you are re-binding it.

Comment: Mutation means that you can call a method on an object and it changes. You have not done that. You have called a method on an object and gotten a completely new thing!

Answer (score 0):

The string's replace method is not a in-place function. It creates a new string.

If instead you tried to run `string[0] = "a"` for example, you would have gotten an error.